# How to return file from applet to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, applet

I have developed an signed applet that is used to upload a file in encrypted form.
This applet I am calling from jsp which is working fine, but my issue is :
Can I call that applet from jsp in such way that will return encrypted file in jsp and I pass that file to server side?
And Can I create multipart file in applet or jsp for that encrypted file and send it to server?

**My running Applet looks like:**

```
public static void encryptDecryptFile(String srcFileName,
            String destFileName, Key key, int cipherMode) throws Exception {
        OutputStream outputWriter = null;
        InputStream inputReader = null;     
        try {                   
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");         
            byte[] buf = cipherMode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE ? new byte[100]
                    : new byte[128];
            int bufl;
            cipher.init(cipherMode, key);           
            outputWriter = new FileOutputStream(destFileName);
            inputReader = new FileInputStream(srcFileName);
            while ((bufl = inputReader.read(buf)) != -1) {          
                byte[] encText = null;
                if (cipherMode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)
                    encText = encrypt(copyBytes(buf, bufl), (PublicKey) key);
                else
                    encText = decrypt(copyBytes(buf, bufl), (PrivateKey) key);              
                outputWriter.write(encText);
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (outputWriter != null)
                    outputWriter.close();
                if (inputReader != null)
                    inputReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Calling jsp looks like :**

```
<applet id="upload" name="upload" code="TestApplet.class" archive="Encrypt.jar" width="360" height="350"></applet>
```

Comment: You can setup a servlet that would accept a stream of file contents and return a stream of file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be using [HttpClient Apache Commons](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/package-summary.html) library. You will have to do something like this in your applet:

```
    public void sendFile throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://yourserverip:8080/yourServlet");

        File f = new File(destFileName);
       
        postMethod.setRequestBody(new FileInputStream(f));
        postMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        client.executeMethod(postMethod);
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
    }
```

This will trigger your servlet doPost() method where you can retrieve the file. As you said, your applet should be signed to be allowed to do this.

Comment: *"your applet should be signed to be allowed to do this."*  Not if the server is the one from which the applet was loaded.  That can be done using a sand-boxed applet.  There are probably other things the applet does that require trust, but 'phoning home' is not one of them.

Comment: With "this" I mean loading a file from the hard drive.

Comment: @EugenioCuevas thank you very much, you solved my big proble. I have function at server side that function accepting multiple parameters and creating MultipartFile. 
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload.works")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("FILE_PRIVACY") String filePrivacy, @RequestParam("FILE_KEYWORD") String fileKeyword,
@RequestParam("FILE_COMMENTS") String fileComments, 
@RequestParam("FILE_TYPE") String fileType,
@RequestParam("FILE_FOLDER") String fileFolder,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){}
So how can I pass this parameters from your given function?

Comment: @EugenioCuevas actually that server side function was calling from jsp using SWFUpload, hence I was getting all parameters. But now I have created Signed applet to upload a file now how should i do that?
Please help me if possible...!

Comment: You can use different methods to get the file in the server side, check the [apache commons fileupload library](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html), check a list of different methods [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=160)

Comment: @EugenioCuevas I just want to know if i write your code in signed applet then how to get that file in my controller? because i am getting request of type of SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper at controller side.